# Eclipse Oxygen for Javascript does not show task icon when there is a TODO comment

Tags: javascript, eclipse, task, comments

In Eclipse Oxygen for Javascript `//TODO` comments are not causing the ask icon mark to show up to left of line numbers.

Is there any fix for it?  In a previous version of eclipse (Indigo), this worked very well.

Comment: What settings do you have in _Window > Preferences: General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Task Tags_?

Comment: I've edited your post for grammar, formatting, and to remove "please help".

Comment: Task tags are enabled but it doesn't work..